# Onmouseout not to run when moving mouse over to certain elements?

Tags: javascript, html

So this code makes an audio clip play when you hover over the `article` elements. The problem is that it stops when the mouse hover on child elements. How can I make the Stopsound function not run when the mouse hover off the general `article`  elements and onto the child elements?

EDIT:Basically I want neither of the functions to run when when alternating which of the child element you hover over.

```js
   function PlaySound(soundobj) {
     var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
     thissound.play();
   }

   function StopSound(soundobj) {
     var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
     thissound.pause();
     thissound.currentTime = 0;
   }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
article24 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
#box24 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#present24 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
#bauble24 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<audio id='mySound' src="http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/278/278903_3546642-lq.mp3"></audio>
<article id="article24" onmouseover="PlaySound('mySound')" onmouseout="StopSound('mySound')">
  <div id="box24">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="present24">
    <a href="">
      <div id="bauble24">
        <p id="belle24">""</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the `mouseout` event triggers whenever the mouse hovers over another element, even if that element is a child of the event's target element.

But, the `mouseover` event will trigger *also* when you stay within the bounds of the parent element, so if you could detect that event before treating the `mouseout` event, you could distinguish between this case and the true leaving of the parent element.

This you can do by delaying the treatment with `setTimeout`, and cancelling that action when you have a `mouseover` event following immediately:

```
var timer = -1; // ID of a timer we will use

function PlaySound(soundobj) {
    clearTimeout(timer); // cancel any pending StopSound action
    var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.play();
}

function StopSound(soundobj) {
    timer = setTimeout(function () { // defer the action
        var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
        thissound.pause();
        thissound.currentTime = 0;
   }, 0); // 0 is enough, as the `mouseover` event is already posted in the message queue
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! The simplest solution is always the best.

Comment: This isnt that big of a deal, but if you change what sub-element you hover on after the clip has finished playing, it starts anew. Do you know a similarly easy fix? If you don't have anything on the top of your head, dont trouble yourself with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery's `.hover` function solves this problem as explained **[here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jquery-events-mouseover-mouseout-vs-mouseenter-mouseleave.htm)**.

NOTE: there are a few seconds delay in my sample file before the audio starts, so when you hover over the `article` wait a moment or two for the music to start.

Also, your `a` and `div` tags were incorrectly nested.

Lastly, I have removed your event binding from the HTML and moved that into the JavaScript, which is highly recommended as inline HTML event binding causes "spaghetti code", is harder debug/scale, causes anonymous global event handling wrapper functions (that alter "this" binidng) to be created and HTML event binding does not follow the much more modern and robust [W3C DOM Event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events) standard

```js
var playing = false;

var audio = document.getElementById("mySound");
var art = document.getElementById("article24");

// We don't really need two functions for start vs. stop
// One function that simply toggles the sound based on 
// a flag will do it. JQuery's .hover method takes two
// arguments (a mouseover callback and a mouseleave callback)
$(art).hover(playStop, playStop);

function playStop(e) {
  // Check to see if we are playing or not and toggle based on that:
  if(!playing){
    audio.play();
    playing = true;
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;      
    playing = false;     
  }
}
```

```css
/* The following is not necessary and is only included to
   be able to visually discern the various child elements */
article { border:10px solid black; padding:10px;} 
div { border:5px solid red;}
div * {border-color: blue;}
div h2 {background:green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id='mySound' src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Mozart%20-%20Presto.mp3"></audio>

<article id="article24">
        
  <div class="box" id="box24">
    <h2>I am in child div #1</h2>
  </div>
        
  <div id="present24">I am child div #2
    <a href="">
      <div id="bauble24">  
        <p id="belle24">I am in child div #2, but am child div #3</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div> 
  
</article>
```

Comment: If you made child divs inside the article tag youd see that once you change which child elements you hover over, the audio clip restarts.

Comment: Moving the attributes to the parent article has the effect I just mentioned. I edited the OP so that the attributes are in the article tag.

Comment: @student42 Please see my updated answer for the solution.

Comment: I see you removed the question, so I removed by remark as well.